# Does Flame Strike Bypass Fire Immunity?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, pathfinder-1e

Half the damage of the Flame Strike spell consists of fire, and the other half is embrued with divine power and, thus, is not subject to reduction from fire-based resistances.  However, does the divinely-powered half of Flame Strike also bypass immunities?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Yes**

[The "divine" half is not Fire damage](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/flameStrike.htm):

> Half the damage is fire damage, but the other half results directly
>   from divine power and is therefore not subject to being reduced by
>   resistance to fire-based attacks.

As it's not fire damage, Fire immunity doesn't apply.